# QTableWidget: What should I do to keep rows selection while clicking among selected rows?

Tags: qt

Mouse clicking among selected items selects current, deselects others.

Comment: What selection mode have you set?

Comment: I have tried all kinds of modes. No one of them is not suitable.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I have changed version 4.8 to 4.6 (comercial) and selection works in normal way.